# git staging all files which should not be staged

Tags: git

I was working on a vistual studio c/C++ project which was not under any version control, All the files were in a my-project directory,

I thought it's time to put it under version control , I copied a .gitignore file my project folder and opened git bash navigated to project directory and did

```
  git init
  git add .
```

Assuming it would obey the .gitignore file. What happened is it has stage all of my files disregarding the .gitignore file so all files under debug folder , release folder obj files etc are all staged

my .gitignore looks like this, template was taken from a wiki answer on stackoverflow about visual studio project git ignore template.

Can you help how to unstage all the files and make them filtered through gitignore ??

```
#OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

#Visual Studio files
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.opensdf
*.unsuccessfulbuild
ipch/
obj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
Ankh.NoLoad

#MonoDevelop
*.pidb
*.userprefs

#Tooling
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.sass-cache

#Project files
[Bb]uild/

#Subversion files
.svn

# Office Temp Files
~$*

#NuGet
packages/

#ncrunch
*ncrunch*
*crunch*.local.xml

# visual studio database projects
*.dbmdl

#Test files
*.testsettings
```

Comment: Are you sure you put the .gitignore file to the right place? git add . wouldn't ignore .gitignore

Comment: Thanks Faruk, I guess I might be doing something wrong, I am check my gitignore and it's encoding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the right `.gitignore` file with the correct encoding at the right place, you can type:

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

Then add all the files again :

```
git add .
```

Comment: git reset says failed to resolve HEAD as valid ref , it never committed yet, so there is not HEAD i suppose

Comment: I also did git rm --cached * and then it says fatal not removing 'debug' without -r

Comment: See the modification, that should work.

Comment: OK faruk, I did git rm --cached -r -f .  without -f it gave an other error, anyways its fixed now

Comment: By the way, the gitignore was not problematic, It was not properly saved :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the .gitignore file first. i git init, then add the readme and ignore files as the 1st commit almost every time.